# What IP I should to specify to get vibed to work on server?

Tags: ip, d, ports, vibed

I have got next situation. There is site. One sub-domain of it map to server inside our network to nonstandard port.

Example: `foo.domain.com` is map to `85.169.223.158` to port `8083`.
Which setting I should set in vibed, to get it work?

The default values:

```d
settings.port = 8080;
settings.bindAddresses = ["::", "127.0.0.1"];
```

I tried specify:

```d
settings.port = 8083;
settings.bindAddresses = ["::", "85.169.223.158"];
```

But I am getting `Failed to listen on 85.169.223.158:8083`.

P.S. I changed IP from real to security reason.

Comment: Use the default values. Or you can omit them entirely.

Comment: try 0.0.0.0 to bind to all interfaces.

Comment: It should work with any ip that you have permission to listen on.

Comment: It's look like variant `0.0.0.0` work, but could I use domain name instead of IP?

Which IP I should use in JS (on client side) one developing stage I used 127.0.0.1 but now it can't load data from it?

Answer (score 0):

Your vibed process should run on machine with the 85.169.223.158 IP. If it does, yet you are getting `Failed to listen on 85.169.223.158:8083`, that means that you have some other process already listening on that port.

Comment: can I use domain subdomain name instead IP? It's seems that IIS used it before (before I rewrote web-app to D)

Comment: But you may not have access to machine with the right IP. That is not the way how it is done. You first make your vibed up and running, and then you configure your web server to redirect calls to whatever IP address vibed is bound to.